# Upload files to One Drive using Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to upload a small word document to a folder in my One Drive using Graph API. I am using this endpoint to create the upload session.

```
POST /users/{userId}/drive/items/{itemId}/createUploadSession
```

It is giving me the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "nameAlreadyExists",
    "message": "Cannot create an upload session on a folder",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-09-22T09:52:51",
      "request-id": "********",
      "client-request-id": "********"
    }
  }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60402838/how-to-perform-a-resumable-upload-to-a-sharepoint-site-not-root-subfolder-usin) and see if it can help.

Comment: Thank you, I understood the issue. I am trying to upload files to a folder. Am I using the correct endpoint to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot work on a folder, but on a file.

```
POST /users/{userId}/drive/items/{folderId}:/{fileNameUploadFile}:/createUploadSession
```

Comment: this always over writes file if present