# upload files in a folder in Sharepoint/OneDrive library using graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

How are we uploading files inside a folder in a SharePoint/OneDrive library(Please note not at the root level of library but inside a folder in a library). The api for uploading it in root level of a library is

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$($SharePointSiteid)/drives/$($LibraryId)/root/children/$filename.txt/creatUploadSession
```

How do I modify the api to include the folder name or Id? How to do it with a folder in library?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the similar HTTP call that is specified below.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/drives/{libraryid}/root:/Shiva 1/Document.docx:/createUploadSession
```

Here `Shiva 1` is my Folder inside my Document Library.

Here `Document.docx` is the document which is already present in my folder.

[image]

You need to provide the name of a file which is already in that folder as this API is used to upload a new version of an already existing document by using the file name.

Comment: Hi Shiva, what do you mean the file should already by present, i am uploading the files in the folder, why do that need to be already present, also I am able to do it in the library level. I followe dyour code above and it gives me Json payload is empty error ifi try to upload inside a folder

Comment: As it is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60402838/how-to-perform-a-resumable-upload-to-a-sharepoint-site-not-root-subfolder-usin) this API is used to create new version of an already existing file.

Comment: Please raise a feature request for this scenario in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that the product team may implement it in future.

Comment: but are you sure, I am able to upload it in a document library , i just want to upload it in a folder inside document library??

Comment: Yes, according to the [endpoints documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0#http-request) it is not specified how to upload file in a document library's folder as the item id indicates its a file. If you give the itemid which is folderid, it is considered as uploading Folder and you will see the error message as shown in the SO Thread link which I provided above.

Comment: @AnkitKumar, you can do it by using the id of the folder, instead of the path.